# Passenger process already running? but its not

Tags: process, nginx, passenger

Trying to start passenger standalone with `passenger start -p 80` and it's saying its already running but when i do a `passenger stop -p 80`i get`According to the PID file '/var/crm/tmp/pids/passenger.80.pid', Phusion Passenger Standalone doesn't seem to be running.`
But it clearly is not because when i try stop it, it says its not running and i cant access it from the web

```
[root@technetium crm]# passenger start -p 80
*** ERROR ***
The address 0.0.0.0:80 is already in use by another process, perhaps another
Phusion Passenger Standalone instance.

If you want to run this Phusion Passenger Standalone instance on another port,
use the -p option, like this:

  passenger start -p 81
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try running `lsof` or `netstat -tlnp | grep 80` to determine which application is using port 80. Once you have that figured out you can do something like ps -elf to kill that process.